Coin Game and Gambler's Ruin
Player A starts with \$1, Player B starts with \$N. Each round a fair coin is flipped, and the bet is the minimum of the 2 stacks.
Heads $\implies$ Player B wins.
Tails $\implies$ Player A wins.
If B has more money than A and then wins, then A busts, and A buys back in for \$1 to restart the next round.
If A has more money than B and then wins, then the game is over.

What is the expected number of rounds (or number of times that A busts) before the game ends? What is the expected profit for A? How does the expected number of times A buys back in change as N increases to a very large value?
If instead, the game also ends when A is down by \$N, what must be the probability of Heads for this to be a fair game?

My inclination here is that if you play long enough, A will eventually win, and so the expected winnings are \$N for A. My concern is that N increases at every time A buys back in, and I am wondering if with a large enough N it is possible that N goes to infinity too fast for B to catch up with a run of N Tails in a row.
I've run some simulations up to N=$10^7$ and found that most of the time A will catch up before a limit $10^9$ buy ins triggers a stop. Analytically, this seems unlikely based on the number of expected number of flips needed to get >$10^7$ tails in a row.
I would love some more rigorous analysis of this problem, and also a proof in either one direction or another that A will always win or lose for a finite N. Is there some critical N where you expect A to start losing?

gambler's ruin

Like the classic gambler's ruin with a fair coin, the probability of a player winning a round in this game is equal to that player's starting stake divided by the total amount of money.
A wins in the first round with probability $\frac1{n+1}$ and loses with probability $\frac{n}{n+1}$ in which case there is a second round.
A wins in the second round with probability $\frac{n}{n+1}\times \frac1{n+2}$ and loses with probability $\frac{n}{n+2}$ in which case there is a third round.
And so on. So the probability there is a $k$th round is $\frac{n}{n+k-1}$ and the probability A wins it, thereby ending the game, is $\frac{n}{(n+k-1)(n+k)}$ making the probability there is a $k+1$th round $\frac{n}{n+k}$.
As $k \to \infty$ you have $\frac{n}{n+k-1} \to 0$ and so there is probability $1$ that A eventually wins the whole game (for an overall profit of $B$'s initial $n$).  But the expected number of games is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{nk}{(n+k-1)(n+k)} =\infty$.

If instead $A$ can only win $n$ or lose $n$ and the coin is fair, then the game must also be fair and so the probability of $A$ winning the game must be $\frac12$ and similarly the probability of $A$ losing the game must also be $\frac12$.  There is no need to bias the coin.
Those did not require meaningful calculation, but another easy way of finding it would be to substitute $k=n$ into the earlier expression $\frac{n}{n+k}$ to give $\frac12$.  Yet another would be $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{(n+k-1)(n+k)}$ which with some effort is also $\frac12$.

For what it is worth, in the restricted game, the expected number of rounds seems to approximately $n \log_e(2) +\frac14 +\frac{1}{16n}$ so for medium sized $n$ roughly $70%$ of $n$.

An interesting point on your accelerated variant of the gambler's ruin is how few flips are expected to be needed per round.  Since there is probability at least $\frac12$ that any flip will lead to one player going bust (it is $\frac12$ unless both players have the same amount in which case it is $1$) the expected number of flips per round is no more than $2$.

Wow, thank you for that response. It is still a bit hard for me to wrap my head around how A can win with probability 1, but the expected number of rounds to win is infinite. Are there any analogous scenarios which might be illuminating on this seeming contradiction?

@zjxs The classic example is a simple unbiased $1$-dimensional random walk starting from $0$, with each step $\pm1$ with equal probability. The probability of ever returning to $0$ in a finite time is $1$, but the expected time until the first return to $0$ is infinite.

That makes sense. Thanks again!

I have one point of confusion which is your claim that the probability A wins in a given round is equal to their stake divided by the total amount of money. I know this would be true in a symmetric random walk, but this case is different since A keeps upping the bet to be all in until they have more money than B. Because of this, A needs a consecutive number of tails to win that is roughly proportional to the log of the size of B's original stake. This means A will often need the same number of flips to win in consecutive rounds, so those probabilities will be the same. Is that wrong?

Let's suppose A starts a round with $1$ and B starts with $n=2^b-1$ for some positive $b$. If A wins once, this goes to $2, 2^b-2$; if A wins again it goes to $4, 2^b-4$ and so on.  Then to win a round, A needs to win $b$ times in a row as otherwise B wins.  Since this is a fair coin, the probability of A winning $b$ times in a row is $\left(\frac{1}2\right)^b$, matching my claim that the probability A wins in a given round is equal to their stake divided by the total amount of money which here is $\frac{1}{1+(2^b-1)}$.

@zjxs But my claim is easier than that.  If A starts with $m$ and B starts with $n$, and the only possible outcomes are A winning everything (say with probability $p$) or B winning everything (probability $1-p$) then, since this is a fair game and the expected position of A is always $m$, you have $p\times(m+n)+(1-p)\times 0 =m$ which gives $p=\frac{m}{m+n}$ as claimed.

I agree with the argument for $n=2^b - 1$. I was less sure about the case for say $n=2^b$, since then you can end up in the scenario where $A_{money} > B_{money}$, and $B$ can win a few before $A$ wins everything. After trying a few examples with a Markov chain setup, it does work out like you say. The claim using the fact the game is fair is very nice.
I did just see your post about the accelerated random walk which I thought was cool.
